# printing a row after finding it in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a model named Object with a column `object_type` in the table. I want to display all records with `object_type = journal` in a table, but I am getting the error **"Undefined index: object_name"**. How am I supposed to call the records?

```php
<tbody>
        <?php
            $type='journal';
            $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
            $criteria->condition = "object_type =:object_type";
            $criteria->params = array(':object_type' => $type);
            $results = Object::model()->findAll($criteria);

            foreach ($results as $value);
            {
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$results['object_name'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$results['object_publisher'].'</td>
                </tr>';
            }
        ?>
```

**WORKING CODE BELOW**

```
<?php
        $type='journal';
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->condition = "object_type =:object_type";
        $criteria->params = array(':object_type' => $type);
        $results = Object::model()->findAll($criteria);

        foreach ($results as $value)
        {
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$value->object_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$value->object_publisher_name.'</td>
                </tr>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: findall() will always return srdClass array.So you have to use '->' to get value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method findAll returns array of CActiveRecord, [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail)

use like this:

```
$value->object_name
$value->object_publisher
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea why only one result is printed? And it is always the newest one added in the database.

Comment: Because of condition or DB data. Re-check your DB data.

Comment: The database is ok, I have 3 records with object_type = journal and only the last one is displayed.

Comment: maybe you override defaultScope method in Object class?

Comment: look sql queries in application.log file

Comment: I am not so advanced, but I can tell you that if I do `var_dump($results);`, all the results are there, but only one is displayed!

Comment: your code like this: foreach ($results as $value);            
  echo '<tr><td>'.$value->object_name.'</td><td>'.$value->object_publisher.'</td></tr>';?

Comment: I'm dumb, it was the unnecessary `";"` after `foreach ($results as $value)`. Thank you Andrey!

Answer (score -1):

You are expecting `$value` to be array, but it's object. Use `$results->object_name`

Comment: @BurhanÇetin sorry, haven't seen you are iterating over $results for $value variable to be single entry and still using $results to print out single entry value, that is wrong.